# Mrtg does not work correctly for some hosts

Tags: centos-7, mrtg

I have configured mrtg to pull date from some ASA devices. But I cannot make It work for Cisco CISCO3945-CHASSIS (revision 1.0) with C3900-SPE150/K9. No graph for GigabitEthernet interfaces have been created. I can do snmplwalk from mrtg server to the router. But when I run env LANG=C /usr/bin/mrtg /usr/local/nagios/etc/someName.cfg I see in output and log below messages.

```
2019-12-23 12:25:08, Rateup WARNING: /usr/bin/rateup could not read the primary log file for someIP_gi0/0
2019-12-23 12:25:08, Rateup WARNING: /usr/bin/rateup The backup log file for someIP_gi0/0 was invalid as well
/usr/bin/rateup: No such file or directory
2019-12-23 12:25:08, Rateup ERROR: Can't open someIP_gi0/0.tmp_17701 for write
2019-12-23 12:25:08: ERROR: Skipping webupdates because rateup did not return anything sensible
2019-12-23 12:25:08: WARNING: rateup died from Signal 0
 with Exit Value 1 when doing router 'someIP_gi0/0'
```

Command `env LANG=C /bin/mrtg --check someName.cfg` does not return any error.

Config was made with command

```
/bin/cfgmaker --community=someStringVal --global "Options[_]: growright,bits" --output=/usr/local/nagios/etc/mrtg/someIP.cfg someIP
```

MRTG version is 2.17.4

Server Centos 7 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, please add your solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The problem was related to my script that was changing the target name to "ip_interfaceName"(ex. Target[SomeIP_cplane]:) but when the interface has not been named the name that was used was for example "gi0/0" the "/" was messing up mrtg workflow.

```
 No such file or directory
```

Was the clue for me.